# How to Pick MAX value based on Where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample Data Set looks like this :

```
Declare @tbl Table (IP VARCHAR(20),IP_Name VARCHAR(30),IP_ID VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.0.0','MOHAN-1','AAAAXDXYM')
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.0.0','MOHAN-2','BBBYYDDMM')
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.1.2','MANASA-1','YYYYMMMD')
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.1.2','MANASA-2','JJJKKKLL')
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.1.3','Vijay-1','XXLLLLXXX')
INSERT INTO  @tbl(IP,IP_Name,IP_ID)VALUES('168.0.1.3','Vijay-2','SSKSKSLL')

Select * from  @tbl
```

**Sample Data** :

```
IP         IP_Name      IP_ID
168.0.0.0   MOHAN-1   AAAAXDXYM
168.0.0.0   MOHAN-2   BBBYYDDMM
168.0.1.2   MANASA-1  YYYYMMMD
168.0.1.2   MANASA-2  JJJKKKLL
168.0.1.3   Vijay-1   XXLLLLXXX
168.0.1.3   Vijay-2   SSKSKSLL
```

I want get the based on the IP's in WHERE Condition .

For Example if I give

```
WHERE IP IN ('168.0.0.0','168.0.1.2','168.0.1.2','168.0.1.3')
```

Output :

```
  IP         IP_Name       IP_ID
168.0.0.0   MOHAN-2     BBBYYDDMM
168.0.1.2   MANASA-1    YYYYMMMD
168.0.1.2   MANASA-2    JJJKKKLL
168.0.1.3   Vijay-2     SSKSKSLL
```

**script** :

```
  ;WITH CTE AS (
    Select *,
ROW_NUmber()OVER(PARTITION BY IP_Name ORDER BY IP_Name DESC)RN from  @tbl WHERE IP IN ()
    )
    Select * from  CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Change the `partition by` to `IP` instead of `IP_Name`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled then it is giving only 3 records

Comment: why two records for ip 168.0.1.2? and not of other IP

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. Seems like Gordon's answer should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it is not giving exact output and it is giving all records

Comment: @PSK the data has been given like that and requirement demands the same

Comment: can you elaborate the requirement, why only 1 record for remaining ip and two for a specific

Answer (score 0):

You want to select a number of rows based on the values passed in.  `WHERE` won't exactly do that, particularly with with `IN`.  Instead, you can enumerate the values in each source and use `JOIN`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ip order by ip_name) as seqnum
      from ?
     ),
     ips as (
      select ip, count(*) as cnt
      from (values ('168.0.0.0'), ('168.0.1.2'), ('168.0.1.2'), ('168.0.1.3')
           ) v(ip)
      group by ip
     )
select
from t join
     ips
     on t.ip = ips.ip and t.seqnum <= ips.cnt;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon I can't  give IP's in Values(). I need to put them in Where condition why because I'm going to wrap this up in View and put those IP's in WHERE condition and more over script is not working

Comment: it is giving all records and not at all coming like output .Can you please look into it @gordon

Comment: @mohan111. . .  This would work if you just modify your `partition` clause with `row_number() over (partition by ip order by ip_name desc)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think by specifying the IP two times like `('168.0.0.0','168.0.1.2','168.0.1.2','168.0.1.3')`,  you want to get two records for that specific IP.

If this is the case, you can try like following.

```
SELECT ip,IP_NAME,IP_ID 
FROM   (SELECT t.*, 
               i.ct, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY t.ip 
                   ORDER BY ip_name DESC) AS seqnu 
        FROM   @tbl t 
               INNER JOIN ( VALUES ('168.0.0.0',1), 
                                   ('168.0.1.2',2), 
                                   ('168.0.1.3',1) )i(ip, ct) 
                       ON t.ip = i.ip) t 
WHERE  t.seqnu <= t.ct 
ORDER BY IP, IP_NAME
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/SPUB86976)

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| IP        | IP_NAME  | IP_ID     |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 168.0.0.0 | MOHAN-2  | BBBYYDDMM |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 168.0.1.2 | MANASA-1 | YYYYMMMD  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 168.0.1.2 | MANASA-2 | JJJKKKLL  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 168.0.1.3 | Vijay-2  | SSKSKSLL  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: below answer is exact same and I don't want to join values I need to put in where condition

Comment: I am sure that you can't do it in where condition unless you hardcode the ip address in the where clause. If harcoding is fine, you can do it

Comment: You need to hardcode in where like "WHERE  t.seqnu <= 1 or  (t.seqnu <=2 and ip='168.0.1.2')" which doesn't look good at all.